# How should flags then edits be handled?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

A user posts a low quality answer - a clarification request. I see it and flag it, then move on. After I leave, the answer is improved, but the edit happens too quickly to be registered separately. A while later, my flag is declined.

Instead of straight-out declining these flags, should they be disputed or left to age?

(And a separate query - can moderators see ***all*** revisions to a post, even those made almost straight after the original post - e.g. those invisible to the general public?)

Comment: Were you able to retract the flag in the time?

Comment: No @SebastianSimon - I only saw the edit after I saw the flag had been declined.

Comment: Yep, I've had this happen to me a few times too. I'd just say not to worry about it, flagging stats don't matter - declined flags are how moderators teach flaggers to flag more effectively, but you did exactly the right thing. I guess you could have watched the answer for 5 minutes so that the grace period expires before flagging, but I don't think flaggers should be expected to have to do something like that

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, always good to have the feedback.